# Can't find NFTs on Multi-Sig Wallet

Tags: nft, gnosis-safe

According to this opensea link: https://opensea.io/collection/enigmanft-eth these NFts are owned by 0xA4226c182f3dec9c6D8c771b9CCE7bFF7E86F3CF which is a multi-sig Gnosis safe (I know because it's my project).

However, when checking https://etherscan.io/address/0xA4226c182f3dec9c6D8c771b9CCE7bFF7E86F3CF I do not see the NFTs coming in and I also can't access them or transfer them in Gnosis Safe App.

Any ideas what the issue could be?